# Work of Static Friction

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction, work

I've looked at multiple sources on this and some claim that static friction can do no work in any situation while others say that it can do work as an external force. A couple of scenarios are: static friction allows a human to walk forward (the system is the human), static friction allows a car to move forward (the system is the car), a crate on a truck moves forward as the truck moves forward (the system is the crate). In which of these cases is static friction doing work and why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can static friction do work?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/175227/)

Comment: Take a look at this, maybe it will clarify your problem https://scripts.mit.edu/~srayyan/PERwiki/index.php?title=Static_friction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Work requires that a force causes (or counteracts) displacement:

$$W=\vec F\cdot \vec x$$

So no, static friction seems unable to do any work, since "static" means no displacement - but...

... there is an exception: *If the thing that exerts the static friction force **is itself accelerating***, then there *is* a displacement since static friction **pulls the object along** and accelerates it.

Seen from the ground, static friction causes a displacement and thus does work. But since I have to say "seen from the ground", this is a matter of perspective, or *frame of reference*.

Usually we assume to consider the frame of reference of the thing that exerts the static friction force. From that's perspective, the object is *not* displaced but stationary, and thus the claim that static friction can never do any work is often heard.

Comment: Can you say more about the case of the car accelerating due to static friction between the tires and the road.  The road is not moving, is it doing work?

Comment: @M.Enns Good question. No, the road doesn't do any work. Seems counterintuitive but is nevertheless the case